# GridView edit fill textbox of form

Tags: c#, asp.net

i make one form which i'm using number of textbox and than fill the gridview

after editing visible in gridview i want to fill textbox of the form click of the edit in

gridview how i can solve it?

Comment: can use `command name` and `command argument` using temple field?

Comment: what you want exactly after clicking on edit button in your page it's display in `gridview` or in `gridview` you have `edit button` on click of gridview edit button values display in `textbox`?

Answer (score 0):

textbox1=datagridView1.SelectedRow[0].Cells["CellName1 or CellIndex1"].value;
textbox2=datagridView1.SelectedRow[0].Cells["CellName2 or CellIndex2"].value;

Like all